# How can I have a Generic method here?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have these methods, and you may think I may have it for the other number types too. Is there any way that I may merge these methods into one generic method?

```
public long GetActiveDepartmentsQuotaOf ( Func<Department, long> exp )
{
    return Departments == null ? 0 : Departments.Where(d => d.Status == 1).Sum(exp);
}

public int GetActiveDepartmentsQuotaOf ( Func<Department, int> exp )
{
    return Departments == null ? 0 : Departments.Where(d => d.Status == 1).Sum(exp);
}
```

I tried this:

```
public T GetActiveDepartmentsQuotaOf<T> ( Func<Department, T> exp )
{
    return Departments == null ? 0 : Departments.Where(d => d.Status == 1).Sum(exp);
}
```

But it wrong syntactically. What is the way out of this situation? I am just curious

Comment: is it just a typo or have you tried separating the `T` from `TGetActiveDepartmentsQuotaOf` ?

Comment: [`Sum()` itself is implemented with multiple overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548890(v=vs.110).aspx), just like your first two methods. There's no `ISummable<T>` or `IAddable<T>` interface (analagous to `IEquatiable<T>`) that you could use to constrain `T`, and you can't say `where T : int or T : long or T : double`. You just can't get there from here (other than something ugly with reflection). I've more than once wished I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work, because the `Enumerable.Sum` method only works on IEnumerables of certain types which can be summed up (e.g. `int`, `double`, `float`).

Here's the full overload list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx

It is unclear how you would sum up an `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` can be anything. Imagine, for example that `T` is `Department`. What would you expect .Sum() to return in that case?

Comment: So I was looking for an answer like @Mong Zhu's. A condition to restrict the usage to certain types. But it still gives the same error too. Hence I don't have much options, either use many methods, or accept converting as romain-aga suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

```
public T GetActiveDepartmentsQuotaOf<T>(Func<Department, double> exp)
    where T : IConvertible
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Departments == null
        ? 0 : Departments.Where(d => d.Status == 1).Sum(exp), typeof(T));
}
```

Edit: See at the end

*But you will have to convert to int (or a double if you can have some decimal numbers) the return value of your lambda (or method).*

---

**EDIT**

If you really need the `Func<Department, T>` signature:

```
public T GetActiveDepartmentsQuotaOf<T>(Func<Department, T> exp)
    where T : IConvertible
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Departments == null
            ? 0
            : Departments.Where(d => d.Status == 1)
                .Sum(d => (int)Convert.ChangeType(exp(d), typeof(double)))
        , typeof(T));
}
```

Edit: I changed the type from int to double in my solution (due to the @Servy's comment), to be sure no one get confused by the change to make to support decimal. At least, now, integers and decimals should work either.
You should also be aware, you can get a loss of precision when using decimals (but I guess only a long decimal part would be affected).

Comment: This isn't going to compute the correct sum for non-integer values, worse still, it doesn't provide any indication of this; the signature would imply that it will properly sum any convertible type, even though it can't.

Comment: It's why I said he can change to double if he need to compute some decimal numbers ;) But, I'm aware the solution I wrote doesn't work with decimals. Since, you said this, I will swap the types, at least no more confusion could be made.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you pick, the point is you can only support *one* type, not *all* of them.  If you change it from using integer sums to double sums, it won't work for non-double sums.  If you change it to use decimals, then it won't work for non-decimal sums.  You need to actually use the sum based on the actual type itself to reliably get the correct result.

Comment: With the conversion of type, it should work, since the result of the sum method will be converted in the type you want. And the magic, it can support string sum too (if convertible to int or double, whatever the type of sum choosen). An integer is a decimal in math, then, with the double sum, you should get the good result. I don't get your point, you might have a detail that I ignore about how sum works beneath, but otherwise this solution seems correct to me.

Comment: an integer can be converted to a decimal, but a double or a float can't (it's a lossy conversion), as is also true of a long (or ulong).

Comment: Yup, that's why I supported the double sum ;) You don't lose anything by converting your int to a double, neither by converting a double to a double. And when you convert back your sum to your int, the sum should be an "integer" with only 0 for the decimal part. So you shouldn't lose anything. I'm not sure about unsigned, but I don't think this will affect the result neither.

Comment: Converting a decimal to a double is lossy, as is a long or ulong.  There is no numeric type in C# to which you can convert every other numeric type to without loss of data.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand what you are saying. But, it's not a problem just for C#, then. Even, in others languages, converting a double to float, or inversely, can cause loss of data/precision. But that will depend on the need of the OP now. If he doesn't need the 10th decimal, I think it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, in every language converting between data types that aren't compatible can result in loss of data, as such one always needs to be careful when performing such conversions to ensure that they are either okay with the loss of data, or know that their specific values won't lose any data.  You cannot make either guarantee.  In order to generically sum the data you need to *avoid converting it to another type entirely* in order to produce the correct result.  It's not that conversions are always wrong, it's simply that you can't use them *in this context*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124319/discussion-between-romain-aga-and-servy).